# click through sticky, transparent iframe

Tags: css, iframe, transparency

I have a webpage where the bottom part is occupied by an iframe that I made transparent to view the overlapped elements.

[image: iFrame]

Although the transparency is working well, the overlapped links are not clickable unless I switch pointer-events to none in the iFrame (which obviously solves the problem by another). I tried making a div into the iFrame, covering the "menuless" part, with pointer-events set to all but it doesn't seem to work. I also have to keep in mind the chat component is sticky.

Comment: So, the iframe essentially is used to include the chat window, right? The expected be for the chat window to be clickable (obviously) and the content behind the rest of the iframe be also clickable? Can you provide a working example on a fiddle, or at least the html structure of your application? edit: just noticed this was asked 6 years ago, but.. who's counting? :)

Comment: Well but he set a bounty today so... I guess it's still relevant.

Comment: @scooterlord not sure you will get any answer, someone else set the bounty not the asker

Comment: The UI for this seems weird. You want the iFrame elements to be clickable, but also the stuff it covers to be clickable? That just seems like a not-great UI choice.

Answer (score 3):

This question is old, but for anyone who stumbles across it...

1. `iFrames` represent another entire DOM wrapped in the parent DOM. Things like CSS `pointer-events` don't typically work on iFrames or function the same way across browsers.
2. You can try to impact all content INSIDE the iframe using `iframe > * {pointer-events: none;}` but if the iframe content crosses domains, it likely won't work.
3. `pointer-events: all;` is intended to work with [SVGs only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Values) not other DOM elements.

**The proper solution for the OP is to either scale the iFrame to only the size of the content OR don't use an iFrame at all.**

Other options to embed content:

1. HTML `<embed>` - [Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp)
2. HTML `<object>` - [Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp)
3. [Web Components HTML Imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports) - Recently deprecated but there's a [polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/html-imports)

None of these are great solutions but depending on the problem they may work.

**Finally, you can use a Javascript call to fill the content of an element with external content.** This is essentially what "Single Page" Apps built using React/Angular/Vue are doing behind the scenes. *Note: If you go this route be sure to pay attention to `CORS headers` if the content is coming from a different domain.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use z-index through css:

The z-index creates a list of the concerned elements in css and the element with the highest number, so for example:

```
#elmnt {
    z-index: 10
}

#anotherElmnt {
    z-index: 20
}
```

The `#elmnt` will have a less importance and will be putted behind the `#anotherElmnt` that has a higher z-index in case of overlapping.